# TestNG/Maven Encoding issue

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I'm using TestNG for my Maven project, using data from an .xlsx file for the test cases. While this data is printed correctly in the Console, TestNG doesn't correctly read certain characters (é to Ã©, Î to ÃŽ, ç to Ã§).

I have tried pretty much every "solution" I could find, but to no avail.

Class file:

```
   @Test(groups = {"customer"}, dataProvider = "customerData", dataProviderClass = Testdata.class, priority = 0)
   public void createCustomer(String cName) throws InterruptedException {
       System.out.println(cName);
       ...
}
```

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="NAV_Integration_TestSuite">
 <test name="Customer creation">
   <classes>
     <class name="test.customer.CRn"/>
   </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

readExcel:

```
    public static Object[][] readExcel(String filepath, String sheetName) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int column = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][column];
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                String val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                data[i - 1][j] = val;
            }
        }
        wb.close();
        return data;
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>NAV_Integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>NAV_Integration</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>NAV_Integration</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <selenium.version>3.14</selenium.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
            <version>3.14.0</version>                               
        </dependency>                                       
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
            <version>6.9.10</version>                               
            <scope>test</scope>                         
       </dependency>
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>                               
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>                                
            <version>4.1.0</version>                            
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>                               
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>                              
            <version>4.1.0</version>                                
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>   
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

.xlsx is UTF-8 encoded. Maven project Text file encoding is UTF-8. I have tried many solutions including different plugin configurations in pom.xml, setting environment variables and different ways to read from an .xlsx file.

Eclipse: 4.13
Selenium: 3.14
TestNG: 6.9.10
Apache POI: 4.1.0

Comment: Why do you have dependencies on maven-plugin-annotations, maven-plugin-api ?

Comment: Sorry, leftover from another "solution" I tried - removed those dependencies from OP

Comment: One more thing the configuration for maven-surefire-plugin contains `intputEncoding` and `outputEncoding` which do not exist...

Comment: Could also explain in detail what you mean by `TestNG doesn't correctly read certain characters...` cause TestNG itself does not read files itself ...only your test code might do ...

Comment: I think it seems issue of Excel cell format. If you can set format in excel cam resolve issue

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for pointing it out. Any thoughts on why it can be printed fine in the Console, but the TestNG results shows the wrong characters?

Comment: @Muzzamil I have tried setting text format and removing all format from the Excel cells. Neither works unfortunately.